# Segue causes error: "Terminating since there is no system app"

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Amongst the Swift users there are a variety of posts like this, where the iOS app crashes with no error messages aside from **"Terminating since there is no system app"**.

I have tried deleting and replacing segues from the storyboard to no avail (as suggested in another post).

The only thing that seems to work, is to reassign `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController`
to the segue destination view controller. But I feel like this is bad practice and also leads to constantly switching the rootViewController around in subsequent segues.

Does anyone have any ideas.